# Is this the correct usage of a comma?

Tags: commas

> The parties were living together until 3/24/20, which is when Janet moved out.

Is the comma used correctly here?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's used correctly.

*which is when Janet moved out* is a supplementary relative, not an integrated, as it doesn't help to define *3/24/20*.

The comma works to separate it prosodically from the rest of the sentence indicating a slight pause in speech.

In writing, the comma serves to mark the fact that the relative is not a modifier of the noun phrase it takes as its antecedent, but a supplement.